# ERROR: null value in column " " of relation " " violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (21, null, null, null, ...)

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I am new on PostgresQL, and I am experiencing the error in the title.

I have table_a with an empty column, which I want to fill up with data from a column in table_b, upon a match.

table_a:

```
id | name | town  | town_id  |

1  | name1 | city1 |  -      | 
2  | name2 | city1 |  -      |
3  | name3 | city2 |  -      |
4  | name4 | city2 |  -      |
5  | name5 | city3 |  -      |
```

table_b

```
id | town_name 

1  | city1 
2  | city2 
3  | city3
```

I want INSERT the table_b.id INTO table_a.town_id ON town = town_name

```
INSERT INTO
    table_a(town_id) 
SELECT 
    table_b.id
FROM
    table_b
JOIN
    table_a
    ON town = town_name;
```

Problem is that I get the error in the title, in a row which is not actually existing (e.g.: table_a has 20 rows, but error is on row 21...). What is happening there? It seems it is correctly inserting the data, but then it does not stop at the end of the table, so the not null constraints is triggered.

Comment: If you want to change existing rows you need to use UPDATE.

Comment: Have you checked that this is not an issue of an index starting with 0?

Comment: - rows are empty, I just added the column to the table

Comment: - I removed the indexes, still the same error. Moreover, if I run the command again, the failing row is increasing by one, so it is 22, then 23, 24... and so on

Comment: INSERT creates new rows, it does not touch existing rows. (unless you have an ON CONFLICT check in your statement). In your case, it looks like you need an UPDATE statement and not an INSERT statement. The comment about an index is really strange to me, no index in the world can change the error that has been made.

Comment: I referred to the index used to keep track of position, not the index regards to performance optimization. In any case, I must have misjudged the issue. Glad you solved it for op :)

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

As suggested by @Frank Heikens I had to use UPDATE

```
UPDATE table_a
SET town_id = table_b.id
FROM table_b
WHERE town = town_name;
```